# How is syscall typically implemented

Tags: linux, windows, multithreading, operating-system

I am implementing something very similar to simplistic OS but I am struggling to grasp what syscalls actually are: 
First of all - in process system which thread does *typically* * execute the interrupt routine(the syscall kernel function) - one of the kernel threads or the user space thread given temporal privilege and routine address?
How would be syscall mechanism implemented in user space - does either of following match roughly what is going on under hood?
Implementation A:

```
//equivalent to assembly
//MOV EAX sys_call_no
//INT 0x80
void* interrupt(int service, void* args)
{
   return kernel::int_vector[service](args);
}
```

Implementation B:

```
//equivalent to assembly
//MOV EAX sys_call_no
//INT 0x80
void* interrupt(int service, void* args, void* ret)
{
   kernel::intr_queue.push_back_syncd(interrupt_context(){kernel::int_vector[service], args, ret});
   waitForServiceCompleted();
   return ret;
}
//in kernel thread
while(true)
{
  while(!intr_queue.isEmpty())
  {
    auto context = intr_queue.pop();
    context.ret = context.func(context.args);
    notifyDone();
  }
}
```

C: I don't understand it at all - it works completely differently. 
 * *by typically I mean most common current desktop systems like window 7/8 or latest Ubuntu distribution*
 note: sorry if this is not the correct SE site to post this question - please comment me to move it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementation A is typically how it works. Operating systems primarily use their own threads only for tasks that don't involve directly responding to a specific process request. When a process makes a typical system call, that thread switches to a kernel stack and begins running kernel code in kernel context.

Comment: Thanks - so there is nothing like syscall queue? (even not for example for reading from HDD?) I was puzzled how arguments of syscall stored in registers were passed to the kernel, this explains it pretty good the thread just keeps them.

Comment: @wondra There definitely are queues of requests of various kinds. But a system call like this is broken into parts. First, the request is issued. Then, if and only if needed, the thread will wait in kernel space for the request to complete. A disk interrupt, for example, might be serviced in whatever thread it happened to hijack and then it might release a thread temporarily blocked in kernel space due to a `read` system call. This keeps system calls that don't need to block as cheap as possible.

Comment: So they are blocked *inside* kernel space? Good to know - it really clears things up. But it brings up another question, if another thread gets the disk interrupt what mechanism notifies the original thread? Look up owner of file descriptor PCB and if it is blocked, it wakes it up (that also implies having mutex for this in PCB)?

Comment: The operating system has a mechanism for a thread to block in kernel space and be unblocked by another thread. Typically, it's just a matter of getting the scheduler lock, changing the thread's state to "ready to run", and then, if there are any idle CPUs, signal them.